# How to controls all data from admin panel for multi tenancy using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created a project using multitenancy and I want a way to control subscriptions and all data customers like accounts and other important data to provide support to customers from the admin panel

please give me a way and example to do that using ASP.NET Core, I'm using a single database approach with tenantId column in every table

Comment: aspnetboilerplate and abp are open source frameworks for multitenant applications, you can review the code and take the examples, https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template and https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples , there repo has examples

Comment: Hi @am441, any update here?

Comment: Hi @Rena no update yet, because I want to get the tenant when the user login

Answer (score 0):

For enabling multiple tenant, you could try EF Core Multi-tenancy.

You could refer [Multi-tenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy).

To filter only current tenant, try something like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    => modelBuilder.Entity<MultitenantContact>()
        .HasQueryFilter(mt => mt.Tenant == _tenant);
```

If you want to query all data by ingoring the current tenant. You could try to add a new property like `DisbleFilter` and then Change the `OnModelCrating` like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    => modelBuilder.Entity<MultitenantContact>()
        .HasQueryFilter(mt => mt.Tenant == _tenant || service.DisbleFilter);
```